# Does python garbage collect variables in a higher scope that will never get used again?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, scope, garbage-collection

For example, in the code:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4] # huge list

y = sum(a)

print( do_stuff(y) )
```

Will the memory for the list `a` ever get freed up before the program ends? Will the `do_stuff` function call have to do all its stuff with `a` constantly taking up memory, even though `a`'s never going to be used again?

And if `a` doesn't get garbage collected, is the solution to manually set `a=None` once I'm done using it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine `do_stuff` did this:

```
def do_stuff(y):
    return globals()[input()]
```

And the user enters `a`, so that the list is used there after all. Python can't know that that won't happen, it would have to read the user's mind.

Consider a trivial case like this:

```
def do_stuff(y):
    return y
```

Now it's clear that `a` doesn't get used anymore, so Python *could* figure that out right? Well... `print` isn't a keyword/statement anymore. Python would have to figure out that you didn't overwrite `print` with something that does use `a`. And even if you didn't, it would need to know that its own `print` doesn't use `a`.

You'll have to delete it yourself. I'd use `del a`. (Unless you *want* `a` to still exist and have the value `None`).

Answer (score 1):

`a` will never be freed unless it goes out of scope (ie. it was in a function to begin with), or you manually set it to `None`.

Python's garbage collector uses a system called [reference counting](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/intro.html#reference-counts). In short, all variables have a reference counter that is incremented when a reference to the variable is created, and decremented when an variable is set to `None` or when it goes out of scope.

Example:

```
a = [999999] # 1 reference, the value [999999] is stored in memory
b = a # 2 references

def foo(x):
    print(x)

foo(a) # 3 references during the function call
# back to 2 references
a = None # 1 reference
b = None # 0 references, the value [999999] is deleted from memory
```

Comment: @KellyBundy that would be because another variable has that value. On my machine, this evaluates to just 2. I'll change the value just in case. As per the first concern, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: For example, `sys.getrefcount(1)` evaluates to 686 on my machine since there are already many variables with the value 1.

Comment: 1 is very different, as that's among the small ints that Python caches. What does `print(sys.getrefcount(999999))` print on your machine? On TIO it [prints 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRKG4spiroCgzr0QDyNJLTy0pSk1Lzi8F8i3BQFPz/38A). What Python implementation/version are you using?

Comment: `print(sys.getrefcount(999999))` Prints 2 for me. I'm using CPython 3.9.5 on IDLE.

Comment: In the interactive window, or when you write that in a script and run that?